# Is it possible to use winusb to communicate with multiple identical usb devices simultaneously?

Tags: c++, windows, usb, winusb

I am using multiple identical devices and i would like to be able to read from them simultaneously. So the Product and Vendor ID are the same for all devices. I am wondering if i will be able to read from them in parallel.

In my opinion i would think that it should be possible because for specific device path, you create a unique winusb handle as well as a unique createfile handle.

However in practice, i realized that it didn't work. I didn't use overlapped structure as i though they were completely separate due to unique createfile handles. The data read from the devices isn't read in parallel, instead it just reads the first device, second, third etc...

I wrote the code in c++ and i would like some advice, thank you.
Would using overlapped structure fix the problem?
Or is winusb not meant to be used this way?

Here is the link to my code,
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qvcGwNLxzJ0oRrFZbtyZ7g0zCU0XUG1n?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning for not using overlapped I/O.  Also, if you want help troubleshooting your code, please click the checkmark to accept my answer below and then post a new question with your code, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The reason i didnt use overlapped is because i used threads instead. I ran each device on a seperate thread. After each read i would take a time stamp. Each read takes about 50 ms. I realised that this reads are not in parallel because the time period between stamps across all devices is always at about 45-50 ms intervals. They are never lower as i would expect. Instead they are actually in series even thou im running them in different threads.

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder if you are somehow each individual read is using up all the bandwidth of USB, or if there is a lock somewhere (maybe in the WinUSB DLL?) that prevents multiple blocking reads from happening at once.  Maybe overlapped I/O would work even if threads don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use WinUSB to talk to two different USB devices in parallel, whether or not they are identical.  You would call `CreateFile` twice with two different paths.  To actually get parallelism, you would either need to use overlapped I/O or use multiple threads.

The point of overlapped I/O is that you can start multiple requests very quickly from a single thread, and the operating system will work on them in parallel, and you can later query to see whether they have been completed.

Comment: How should i post my code? its around 200 lines i think?

Comment: If you want help debugging it and you have spent time simplifying it and making it legible, and you can explain what's going on, then sure.

Comment: Hello, im not really allowed to ask another question for the next 2 days, but here is the link to part of my code. I am welcome to be critiqued as i believe thats how i can improve. In the mean time i will implement overlapped and see if that will work. thank you very much! hope everything is going well. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qvcGwNLxzJ0oRrFZbtyZ7g0zCU0XUG1n?usp=sharing

Comment: I ended up using overlapped but that didnt work. I also out of desperation build and ran two separate applications, one for each device , to print the time. This also showed that it doesnt work. I am assuming this is something to do with winusb.sys. Any idea on how i can overcome this? Thank you very much.

Comment: What bus speed do your devices use (e.g. Low Speed, Full Speed, etc.)?  How much data are you reading when you submit a read request?  What type of endpoint is it (bulk, interrupt, etc.)?  When you are running multiple programs, what metric are you looking at to determine that it is not working?  What is the expected value of that metric if your system were working fine?

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding to me. Its a USB 2.0 USB device. By running tail -f /var/log/kern.log command on linux, i got information saying that its a high-speed USB device. (Not sure the difference between the full-speed and high-speed). The wMaxPacketSize of the endpoint descriptor is 512 bytes, however i have been reading 16224 bytes with each WinUsb_ReadPipe transfer (each read takes about 4-5ms).

Comment: Its a bulk type endpoint. After each read i take a getsystemtime. Then i combine all the times and look at the difference in a histogram. I was expecting for period to be very messy, ranging from 0ms to 5ms. However what i obtained was an orderly ~5ms intervals. Thank you very much, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your story is pretty incomplete; I'm not sure exactly how many reads you are doing and how you are timing them (your explanation in the latest comment doesn't make sense to me), and whether you are still using multiple EXEs or what.  One general tip to get better throughput is to make your transfer size a multiple of the endpoint max packet size, and then turn on WinUSB's RAW_IO mode.

Comment: My apologies, I am continuously reading, I take approx 10000 reads whenever I am testing the program. I time them by using a windows GetSystemTime function after each read is finished. I use the same method to time them whether I am using one or multiple EXEs. Thank you for the tip, i will make sure that I am reading a multiple of 512 bytes and look into WinUSB's RAW_IO mode.

Comment: OK, so then why do you expect reads to take 0ms to 5ms?  How could it possibly take 0ms if you really are timing the time from when the read request was submitted to when it is complete?

Comment: Because I am reading from multiple devices and comparing time from all the read calls across all the devices. Devices are running on separate threads hence I was assuming that the period between all the reads would be chaotic, random ranging from 0 to 5ms. But instead its at 5ms, meaning that even thou i have multiple read calls to different devices in separate threads they are still happening one after another.

Comment: From reading on the web, i found that reading pipe without using a Overlapped structure will block other calls. Hence, using Overlapped was the right call, thank you. So the problem might be in me not using Overlapped accurately. I will be trying to fix that. Hmm, i guess my question would be, if i make 2 overlapped calls in 2 separate threads at the exact same time ( and lets say the data transfer from endpoint takes 100 ms to complete ) will i get data transferred back at approximately the exact same time from the devices? Thanks, sorry for the troubles.

Comment: It depends on the details of your setup, like whether the devices are on the same physical USB bus, how much USB bandwidth these transfers actually take, and how the Windows drivers happen to schedule things.

Comment: Hello, I have tried using threads and overlapped but it doesn't seem to work. Hmm i checked and they are plugged in to the different ports but the same bus. That seems like a more likely cause for my problem. Thank you very much! After a bit of a google search it seems like motherboards usually come with only one USB bus for controllers and many ports.

Comment: So if i get a PCI to a usb host controller, that theoretically should solve the problem from what i believe?